# How to script this mass rename function?

Tags: sed, scripting, osx, rename

There are 4 folders in my current working directory. Each folder contains several files named with the following format :

```
HEXA DECA - Season 01 Episode 01 - name of episode
HEXA DECA - Season 01 Episode 02 - name of episode
```

I want to rename this to :

```
HE'XA DECA - S01E01 - name of episode
HE'XA DECA - S01E02 - name of episode
```

`sed` is bit too daunting for me. What's the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that `vidir` is the most flexible and transparent solution for these problems. There you just edit the text file with filenames by whatever means (in VIM or another editor), and changes apply.

Comment: Link: https://github.com/madx/moreutils/blob/master/vidir.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use `mmv` for this kind of task. Others use `rename`. My attempt (not tested, obviously, so try first with the `-n` option):

```
for dir in ....; do
    ( cd "$dir"; mmv -r "HEXA DECA - Season ?? Episode ?? - *" "HE'XA DECA - S#1#2E#3#4 - #5" )
done
```

I `cd` first into `$dir` instead of doing `mmv "$dir/..."` which is also possible. This is to avoid situations where your directory may contain mmv's special characters like `?` or `*`.

Answer (score 0):

`rename` command does what you need:

```
find . -type f -exec rename "s/^(.*\/)HEXA DECA - Season ([0-9]*) Episode ([0-9]*) (.*)\$/\$1HE'XA DECA - S\$2E\$3 \$4/" {} \;
```

We need backslashes 'cos in single quotes `'` can't be escaped, but in double quotes we must escape `$` character.

Here we find all files in directory and sub-directories and trying rename them.

`s/regexp/smth` will substitute all `regexp` matches to `smth`.

`^(.*\/)` is first part of path, everything without base name, saved to `\$1`.

`HEXA DECA - Season` and `Episode` are parts what won't saved, but they are templates for matching.

`([0-9]*)`s are number of season and episode, saved to `\$2` and `\$3`.

`(.*)$` is the last part of string, contains episode name, `\$4`.

In second part of `s///` we substitute `\$N`s into pattern as we want see them.

Comment: Sorry for the first case without `find` — i didn't pay attention to subfolders.